# Ordering a Javascript array by object properties contained in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My first array looks like this:

```
[
    {entityId: 1, name: 'Total sales'},
    {entityId: 2, name: 'Total customers'},
    {entityId: 3, name: 'Reach'}
]
```

I have a second array which stores `entityId`s, and I need to sort the first array using the values of the second array. So, if my second array looks like this:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

then my first array should be sorted like this:

```
[
    {entityId: 1, name: 'Total sales'},
    {entityId: 3, name: 'Reach'},
    {entityId: 2, name: 'Total customers'}
]
```

I know I can sort an array based on object properties by using the `sort` method with my own callback:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    // ... sorting logic ...
});
```

However I'm struggling to wrap my head around how the sorting logic will follow the sorting rules imposed by the second array, rather than just comparing two neighbouring elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var arr = [
    {entityId: 1, name: 'Total sales'},
    {entityId: 2, name: 'Total customers'},
    {entityId: 3, name: 'Reach'}
];

var indArr = [3, 1, 2];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return indArr.indexOf(a.entityId) - indArr.indexOf(b.entityId);
});

console.log(arr);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/680a5oub/).

Comment: Concise, but as pointed out by Grundy, very slow as it calls *indexOf* twice on each iteration. It's very much faster  (maybe [*1,000 times faster on a big array*](http://jsperf.com/sort-with-indexof-vs-map-and-reduce/3)) to not call *indexOf* at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant, possibly better for big array, because iterate over arrays just twice. In case `indexOf` - iterate twice on every calling sort callback.

first, create map from first array

```
var array = [
    {entityId: 1, name: 'Total sales'},
    {entityId: 2, name: 'Total customers'},
    {entityId: 3, name: 'Reach'}
];

var map = array.reduce(function(acc,el){
    acc[el.entityId] = el;
    return acc;
},{});
```

second, just map second array

```
var indexes = [1, 3, 2];

var result = indexes.map(function(index){ return map[index];});
```

naive [**test in jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/sort-with-indexof-vs-map-and-reduce/3)

Comment: "Better" in what way?

Comment: @RobG, just two time go over by array, in case with sort - `indexOf` go over array twice on ever call sort callback

Comment: @Grudy—cool, just pointing out that when you say "better" you need to say why. ;-) You should include a plain *reduce* method without map in your jsperf example.

Comment: @RobG, you mean your version from comment? `a.reduce(function(acc, obj){return (acc[b.indexOf(obj.entityId)] = obj) && acc}, [])`?

Answer (score -1):

Simplest code would be:

```
var a = [
    {entityId: 1, name: 'Total sales'},
    {entityId: 2, name: 'Total customers'},
    {entityId: 3, name: 'Reach'}
];

var b = [1,3,2];
var c = b.slice(); //create copy

for (var i = 0;i< a.length;i++)
{
   var indexOf = b.indexOf(a[i].entityId);

   c[indexOf] = a[i];
}

console.log(c)
```

try the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asadpalekar/36vfrv1L/)

Comment: true. He answered while i was preparing this.

Comment: Consider: `a.reduce(function(acc, obj){return (acc[b.indexOf(obj.entityId)] = obj) && acc}, [])`. Doesn't use *sort* though.